# Trying to get YouTube API iFrame to reinitialize when there are multiple YT videos on one page. State remains the same making it difficult to track

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, adobe-analytics, adobe-launch

YouTube Video API (iFrame) trying to reinitialize with more than 1 youtube video on page. Adobe Analytics

Here is the snippet I am using that was provided to me:

```
/*Video Code Block 1 of 2: Append Enable JS API Parameter and Unique Video ID for Video Tracking.*/
var n=0;

jQuery('iframe').each(function() {
 
 var src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
 
if(src){
    if (src.indexOf('youtube.com') > -1) {
     
        if (src.indexOf('?') > -1) {
            if (src.indexOf('enablejsapi') == -1) {
                src = src + '&enablejsapi=1';
            }
        } else {
            src = src + '?enablejsapi=1';
        }

        jQuery(this).attr('src',src);
        jQuery(this).attr('id','player' +n);
        n++
    }       
 }     

});

/*Video Code Block 2 of 2: Add event listener and fire _satellite.track rules. */ 

try {var addYoutubeEventListener = (function() {

    var callbacks = [];
    var iframeId = 0;

    return function (iframe, callback) {

        // init message listener that will receive messages from youtube iframes

        if(iframeId === 0) {
            window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {

                if(e.origin !== "https://www.youtube.com" || e.data === undefined) return;
                try {
                    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                    if(data.event !== 'onStateChange') return;

                    var callback = callbacks[data.id];
                    callback(data);
                }
                catch(e) {}
            });
        }

        // store callback
        iframeId++;
        callbacks[iframeId] = callback;
        var currentFrameId = iframeId;

        // sendMessage to frame to start receiving messages
        iframe.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var message = JSON.stringify({
                event: 'listening',
                id: currentFrameId,
                channel: 'channelnameofyourchoice'
            });

            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, 'https://www.youtube.com');

            message = JSON.stringify({
                event: "command",
                func: "addEventListener",
                args: ["onStateChange"],
                id: currentFrameId,
                channel: "channelnameofyourchoice"
            });
            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, 'https://www.youtube.com');
        });
    }
})();

addYoutubeEventListener(document.getElementById("player0"), function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    switch(e.info) {
        case 1:
            _satellite.track("video_start");
            break;
        case 0:
            _satellite.track("video_end");
            break;
        case 2:
            _satellite.track("video_pause");
    }
});}

catch(err) {console.log("Video Tracking Not Present");}
```

My thing is, when I play the first video, YT.PlayerState.PLAYING sets to 1, when I pause the video and open another video, YT.PlayerState.PLAYING still remains at 1 so therefore, I cannot trigger my success event to fire.

***Note**: I cannot use the extension adobe has built in because that extension completely makes all of my videos disappear from the page so i'm going with the method mentioned above.*

Trying to find a way to reinitialize it so when a new video opens up, all the parameters reset and I can trigger my success events

Comment: Myabe it's because you're refferin only to `player0`? - see this line in your code: `addYoutubeEventListener(document.getElementById("player0")` - it would be nice if you use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or any other online code editor to test your code. Please see **how to create a [mcve]**.

Comment: Hi @MauricioAriasOlave thanks for your reply, i thought the same as well but what if they share the same ID? There's a page with 7 items (youtube videos), when a user clicks one of the items to play, a modal/lightbox pops up with the iframe youtube embed code, they have the same id "player0" and I user the youtube API, the first video is the only one that gets picked up for the start, end and pause. when i close the modal/lightbox and select another video w/ the same id "player0" it doesn't capture the youtube start,end,pause.